# Difference between Azure price calculator and actual configured price - have I missed something?

Tags: windows, ftp, azure

I am setting up our organisation's first Azure server as a kind of test bed for future projects.  We would like to create a simple FTP/SFTP server as an Azure Windows server.

The [Microsoft pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/calculator/#virtual-machines1) for a Windows Server - Basic A1: 1-Core 1.75GB RAM 40GB comes in at £0.026/hour or £19.41 per month.

When I create a Windows server in the Azure Portal, the cheapest I can possibly create is £54.90 per month - nearly three times as much.

Is it possible to account for the difference, other than through over-enthusiastic marketing?

I've tried both 2008 R2 and 2016 servers, and I'm not choosing HPC machines or anything high-end at all.

By the way, I realise I can probably get a web-based subscription FTP service much cheaper

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the VM selector will select SSD for your disk type, this will only show the *S series VMs (DS, ES, FS etc.) which are more expensive. The A series, which is the cheapest option will not be shown.

Change the drop down to HDD and make sure you click the "show all" option on the VM selection window and you should see the A series VMs which are the cheapest.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  When building a new VM you can specify SDD/HDD in the Basics section 1, but it then becomes selectable as an option in section 2 - Size.  Changing it in section 2 seemed to make no difference if it was already set to SSD in Section 1.

So I changed it in section 1 to HDD and then lots of VM options were available in Section 2.

Comment: Yeah, I have noticed that, not sure why its there really. You do need to do it on the first page.